# Unknown field error when importing records with Inspector

Tags: data-export, data-import

I'm trying to import records from one sandbox to another that is a exact copy withouth records.

I export CSV records with Inspector from one sandbox. Problem is when I paste CSV data in Import Records. A lot of fields are detected as unknown, for example, ID field.

Why is happening this?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if we have enough info to work off of here. Here are some debug steps I would start with:

1.) Ensure inspector is pointing to the correct org. Sometimes when you have multiple orgs on different tabs, things can get mixed up.

2.) Ensure you are importing the correct object type.

3.) Is the CSV formatted correctly? Try pasting what is on your clipboard into a simple text editor to make sure it looks like a true CSV. (What software are you copying the CSV from?)